# Custom font for EmojiCompat

Tags: android, fonts, android-support-library, emoji

I have a small problem regarding the [EmojiCompat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html) library which was introduced some weeks ago.
There is a group of people (including me) who don't quite like the new Emoji style, Google has introduced with Oreo.
As I like the good old blob emojis, I recently started updating this emoji font.

Now my problem:
The Android developer page shows that there are two ways of using `EmojiCompat`.
The first one is using downloadable fonts and the second one is using this bundled emoji font which is based on loading font assets.
I already have a working implementation of `EmojiCompatConfig` which allows me to load any font I have in my `assets`-folder and it works with the font provided in the bundled configuration but not with my own font.
The section  "Library-Components" [I don't have enough/any reputation, so I can't provide a link to this section...] says the original Noto-Emoji font (which my font is actually based on) is *modified* in some way (i.e. moving the emojis into another area and adding some "*Extra emoji metadata*" which isn't really specified anywhere in the documentation).
I already tried to look for some differences using the `ttx` tool provided by `fonttools`.
It looks like these modifications are the only ones made.
The modified version differs in both the `meta`-table not present in the default noto font and in the actual positions the emoji glyphs have - probably because they movede the emojis to the private area.
Does anyone know how to recreate these modifications so I am able to use my own emoji font instead of that *new* one?
I already tried to search for this issue but I didn't find anything that could help me.

There has already been [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254967/android-emoji-compat-use-ios-emojis) regarding whether or not it would be possible to use the iOS emojis using the downloadable font approach but I don't think these questions are the *same*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script to modify an existing CBDT/CBLC emoji font can be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/noto-fonts/+/android-8.0.0_r17/emoji-compat/createfont.py

The "unicode path" that needs to be passed to the script should point to this data: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/unicode/+/android-8.0.0_r17